# How do I add a custom Zope2 catalog index with plone.indexer?

Tags: plone, zope, catalog

I'm trying to add a custom catalog index based on the recommendation here:

- http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searching_and_indexing/indexing.html#custom-index-methods

[My code](https://github.com/aclark4life/event_days_indexer) looks like this (h/t: supton):

```
from plone.indexer.decorator import indexer
from Products.ATContentTypes.interfaces.event import IATEvent
from Products.ATContentTypes.utils import DT2dt

@indexer(IATEvent)
def event_days(context, **kw):
    start = DT2dt(context.getStartDate())
    end = DT2dt(context.getEndDate())
    delta = end - start
    return delta.days
```

Registered with the following ZCML:

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:five="http://namespaces.zope.org/five"
    xmlns:genericsetup="http://namespaces.zope.org/genericsetup">

    <five:registerPackage package="." initialize=".initialize" />

    <genericsetup:registerProfile
        description="event_days_indexer"
        directory="profiles/default"
        name="default"
        provides="Products.GenericSetup.interfaces.EXTENSION"
        title="event_days_indexer"
    />

    <adapter name="event_days" factory=".indexers.event_days" />

</configure>
```

Everything seems to load fine, but when I create a test event and reindex the catalog, the index remains empty. What am I missing?

Comment: Ehm, are there anything in the logs?

Comment: @Yuri: There won't be if there was an AttributeError.

Comment: @aclark: Don't tell me you don't know how to put a `pdb.set_trace()` in that indexer.. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters Actually I had one above the function to inspect IATEvent, but it didn't occur to me to go further (I would expect a traceback).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object will not be considered for an index if the indexer hits an AttributeError.

In this case that happens because ATContentTypes specifies custom accessors for the startDate and endDate fields. Instead of context.getStartDate() and context.getEndDate(), use context.start() and context.end()

Comment: Thanks! I won't ask why there was no traceback…

Comment: @aclark: Indexers always swallow AttributeErrors (they then index `Missing.MV` aka "missing value").

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, thanks. Is there somewhere I can look to find missing values? (vs. seeing zero results in portal_catalog)

Comment: @aclark: Ah, no, I had that wrong; indexes generally insert nothing at all when the method raises AttributeError, and the CatalogBrain value will be `Missing.MV` for such columns.